# Top aligning a div inside a div, not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to top align a div with in another div, but as you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrcRz/ it doesn't work right. I am wanting to top align this div:

```
 <div class="top_aligned">
     test
 </div>
```

Comment: which one u want to top align i can't find the div class named top_aligned in your jfiddle

Comment: do you want the video to be vertically aligned or the "JOIN" text??

Comment: you can see the text is vertically aligned as top... check http://jsfiddle.net/GrcRz/2/

Answer (score 0):

The code you are writing here in your question is naming your div "top_aligned". So you need to style it in your CSS code.

.top_align {

}